# Does anyone discuss the similarities between these?

Tags: words, parashat-bereishit, mishnah-berurah

I noticed that the משנה ברורה and בראשית both talk about רוח ,מים, clothing, and 'ה seeing all in the beginning. The משנה ברורה seems to be alluding to the חומש here.

The first thing after the famous יתגבר כארי is the laws of washing one's hands (מים/water) because of רוח רעה (bad spirit).

Then the משנה ברורה talks about dressing modestly, which is reminiscent of the conversation that Adam had with G-d after eating from the tree of knowledge. The משנה ברורה says:

> ״אל יאמר הנני בחדרי חדרים מי רואני כי הקב״ה מלא כל הארץ כבודו״

Paraphrased into English:

> A person shouldn't say "I'm indoors, who can see me?" because G-d's glory fills the whole world.

Similarly, when Adam ate from the tree of knowledge, he realized that he wasn't properly clothed, and G-d asked him who told him that he was naked.

There are other interesting parallels here, and I wonder if anyone has written or discussed this before. (Another illusion, to שמות/Exodus might be between the ordering of shoes and Jacob/יעקב switching his hands when blessing his grandchildren.)

Do any sources discuss these similarities or why their significance might be?

*Edit:* I didn't realize that the top of the page in the משנה ברורה is actually the שולחן ערוך. Same story, different ספר.

Comment: Jews really hold the Torah to a great deal of respect, by trying to copying its style is a way to show love and respect

Comment: We even see it in interactions between men and women "Another unconscious sign of attraction is mirroring, or matching another person’s movements. When people are interested in one another, researchers have found that they tend to mimic each other’s movements and gestures."

Comment: You could make this question more compelling by [edit]ing in more details about the parallel references. I'd also suggest recasting it as the M"B apparently echoing Bereishit rather than as two "parallel" books.

Comment: It seems as if you have your proper idea. may be that you can begin with an idea and ask about it. actually the question is not clear: parallel between mishna brura and chumash Bereshit? or allusion to bereshit in mishna brura? please help people to read the question.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the Mishna Berura. The Mishna Berura is based on the Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim which was authored by Rabbi Yosef Karo.

Comment: @GershonGold I'm not misquoting the MB though. I may be confusing the source, for sure. But the similarities are still there.